# How to validate an input type="text" element to only accept certain content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I have a text input field:

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
```

Is there a way to format the input field to only allow certain text to be valid?

For example: In that particular text field, the user must input an email address which ends in `@hotmail.co.uk`. Any other email domains such as `@yahoo.com` will not be valid and therefore will show an error when clicking submit (Will not register the user).

Comment: masked input jquery plugin for example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [HTML5 `pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) to validate whether the string ends with `@hotmail.co.uk`.

In this case you can use the following regular expression:

```
^.*@hotmail\.co\.uk$
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email" pattern="^.*@hotmail\.co\.uk$" size="25" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could also just attach an `input` event listener to the element and check manually. This is just a basic example, feel free to customize to your needs. I would still suggest validating that the value is a valid email address by using the regex from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript).

```js
$('input[name="email"]').on('input', function(e) {
  var isValid = this.value.match(/^.*@hotmail\.co\.uk$/) !== null;
  $(this).toggleClass('isValid', isValid);
});
```

```css
.isValid {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I added some additional options based on this answer in my answer below, maybe it can help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Extended answer using the "pattern" attribute (from Josh Crozier):

After the user changed the value of the input you can check it for a valid input:

In addition you could test the input while the user is typing the value and highlight the border:

```js
function check(el) {
  if (new RegExp(el.pattern).test(el.value) == false) {
    alert("Bad Input")
  }
}

function test(el) {
  if (new RegExp(el.pattern).test(el.value) == false) {
    el.classList.add("bad")
  } else {
    el.classList.remove("bad")
  }
}
```

```css
.bad {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="^.*@hotmail\.co\.uk$" onchange="check(this)" oninput="test(this)" type="text" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

many solutions are available:

validate form with javascript.

use 2 inputs: a text input for the username and a select options or radio buttons for "@site.com"

pattern attribute on input